# How to clear sql results grid

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wonder. is there a way to clear sql results grid ? Icant find it anywhere
like Clear, Remove like that

[image]

Comment: Are you requesting multiple datasets in your query?

Comment: If you don't want an empty result set, check the result set would not be empty before selecting it.

Comment: **No**, There is not.

Comment: @AnthonyHorne Yes but I want someting like
if resultCount = 0
 clearOldRecords (I mean remove column names)
run newquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CTRL+R Hides / Displays Results Grid

Edit / Update - If I understand correctly:

```
IF EXISTS(Select ColKey from BOB)
BEGIN
   SELECT Col1, Col2 FROM BOB
END
```

Edit / Update - More possible scenarios:

```
DELETE FROM BOB
WHERE SomeCriteria = True
```

Comment: There is no problem if you can't see it. +1

Comment: please check question again :)

Comment: @PsyGnosis Can you post the queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform a select @cnt = COUNT(*) FROM <<>>

Then if @cnt > 0 perform the select statement

Comment: I want to delete old results